# uncaught TypeError cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to console.log the value submitted by a form but getting "uncaught TypeError cannot read properties of undefined" Error. I'm not sure why.

HTML

```html
<form action="" id="p2Input">
    <input type="text" name="" id="guess" placeholder="Guess a letter">
    <input type="submit" value="Guess">
                     
</form>
```

JavaScript

```js
function processGuess(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //this is where the error shows
    let guess = document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("Submit",null);
    console.log(guess);
}
```

Comment: How is `processGuess` being executed?

Comment: I was testing it out by calling it in the console.

Comment: Then you haven't supplied an event as an argument.

Comment: Pardon the confusion. So, I have a form that I'm testing where I type a letter and then hit the submit button. I am then attempting to have that letter print to the console to ensure it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `processGuess` when form has submitted, you can do it, by defining `onsubmit` on your form, like this:

```js
function processGuess(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    let guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
    console.log(guess);
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="p2Input" onsubmit="processGuess(event)">
  <input type="text" name="" id="guess" placeholder="Guess a letter">
  <input type="submit" value="Guess">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped removed the error, but is logging undefined in the console.

Comment: You're welcome, Did you type anything in the `guess` input?

Comment: I did, but still getting undefined.

Comment: In the above snippet or in a different code?

Comment: It works in the above snippet but when I test it in the browser from my code file it doesn't log the guess.

Comment: Could you add your code here or in the question?

Comment: function processGuess(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let guess =document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener('Submit',null);
    console.log(guess);

}

Comment: remove `let guess = document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener('Submit',null);` and instead put `let guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;`